# grails 2.3.5 + redis-gorm plugin + spring security core plugin

Tags: spring, grails, redis

I have problem in running a Grails 2.3.5 app with Redis as data store and Spring Security Plugin?
I get this "funny" message when submitting login form (brand new grails project with spring-security-core and redis-gorm plugins installed and User, Role, Requestmap classes generated with s2-quickstart command):

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error 
URI 
/test-redis-security/j_spring_security_check 
Class 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
Message 
No transactionManager bean configured 
Trace 
 Line | Method
->>  706 | withTransaction in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run             in java.lang.Thread


    Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security Core is set up by default to need transactions and the redis-gorm plugin doesn't support them. You will need to override most the services provided by spring security code to not need transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeff, can you please explain step by step how to do this override process ?

Comment: Start with the installed classes and make sure none of them have transactional calls in them. After that you will need to look at the source of the spring secuirty core and see what methods are requiring transactions and start overriding them with your own. Look for Burt Beckwiths hacking spring security talks